# After the verb "be", is there "the fact that" or just "that"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs, restrictive-clauses

> 1. The difference between x and y is **that** x is produced by z.
> 2. The difference between x and y is **the fact that** x is produced by z.
> 3. **That** x is produced by z is the difference between x and y.
> 4. **The fact that** x is produced by z is the difference between x and y.

I am wondering if they mean the same thing. If they are not, please tell me the difference.

I am wondering if always the phrase ***the fact*** exists in deep structures of the sentences as above.

Comment: Your second sentence is not correct. "The fact" is not needed there, only "that" is okay. As for #3 and #4, the correct is #4. I don't want to comment about #3, as I am not sure about that sentence.

Comment: Nima, I want to modify my previous comment. All the four sentences you quoted are all right. But I just one to comment that in these sentences "the fact" is not necessary. What I mean to say is that the same meaning can be rightly conveyed through only the *that-clause*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they all mean the same thing. Yes, you could read "that" as meaning "the fact that". It is more common to leave "the fact" out, except for emphasis. Both #3 and #4 are grammatically correct, but awkward; #1 and #2 would be considered to be more straightforward.

Comment: ManFromIndia: Please explain when "the fact that" is needed, and what difference in meaning is conveyed when it is included. I only see that you say it is not needed in #2 but is needed in #4. Can you describe a difference in meaning in the four OP examples, or supply other examples to make this clear?

Answer (score 0):

All your four sentences are correct.

Here is a note about **the fact that** clause -

A *that-clause* can't take a preposition before it. In some cases it is hard to drop the preposition before *that-clause*. In such cases to solve the problem we can use **the fact that** clause.

> 1. Marxism is on the rise again simply **owing to the fact that** capitalism has transmogrified into something unqualifiedly sinister, frightening and odious, threatening to undo much of the social progress made in the 20th century.
> 2. The judge paid a lot of attention *to* **the fact that the child was unhappy at home.**
>
>    - The judge paid a lot of attention to that the child was unhappy at home. (INCORRECT)

Sometimes we can use **the fact that** clause as the subject of the sentence -

> **The fact that Simon hadn't been home for three days** didn't seem to worry anyone. (This sentence is more natural than *That Simon hadn't been home for three days didn't seem to worry anyone*.)

**The fact that** can legitimately be used as a noun phrase in apposition to a following noun clause.

> **The fact** *that he wrote her a letter* suggests that he knew her.

When *the fact that* can be avoided, it should be.

> Aniston objects to **the fact that** Hollywood puts pressure on women to be thin.

In this sentence we can avoid *the fact that* and rewrite it the following way (though there is a slight difference in meaning between the two sentences) -

> Aniston objects **the way** Hollywood puts pressure on women to be thin.

Consider the following sentence  -

> **The fact that he is a millionaire** has nothing to do with it.

We can drop **the fact** and retain the same meaning with *that-clause* as the nominal clause (subject) of the sentence, but some emphasis is lost.

In some cases it's not avoidable -

> He has learned to laugh again at little ironies, such as **the fact that** he, unlike several of his rescuers, did not get poison ivy that day.

Though using only *that-clause* and dropping **the fact** doesn't make the sentence incorrect, but the sentence as written above is better. (as pointed out by @snailboat, @CopperKettle and @CarSmack. Thank you for clarifying)